# How can I use a LINQ projection with List<MyStructure> to get a NameValueCollection?

Tags: c#, linq, namevaluecollection

I have a

```
var list = new List<MyStructure>();
```

I want to extract `MyStructure.Foo` and `MyStructure.Bar` and put these two in a `NameValueCollection`. I want `NameValueCollection` because I am using `WebClient.UploadValues()`

The following creates an `IEnumerable<NamedValueCollection>`. I need just a `NameValueCollection`

```
var nameValueCollection = structure.Select(x => new NameValueCollection             
        { 
            { x.TypeId.ToString(), x.Value } 
        });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to use LINQ here

```
foreach(var myStruct in list)
{
   myNameValueCollection.Add(myStruct.Foo, myStruct.Bar);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am over complicating.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following.

```
        class MyStructure
    {
        public string Foo { get; set; }
        public string Bar { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var list = new List<MyStructure>();
        NameValueCollection nameValueCollection = new NameValueCollection();

        list.ForEach(x => {
            nameValueCollection.Add(x.Foo, x.Bar);
        });

    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I am going to accept keyboardP's answer because he was first but thanks for the extension method syntax.